# How to test if authentication is not failed without sending message?

Tags: java, email, jmail

I'm trying to find out if authentication configurations are filled correctly. But I don't want to send message to catch `AuthenticationFailedException()`. How can I catch this exception without sending? I've got few fields:

- mail
- smtp
- port
- password

If they're incorrect, exception should be thrown.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'authentication configurations are filled correctly'?  Are these validations client side validations like email format check or password length check? If so you can do it on client end. Other than that if you need to see if username/password is valid then you have to communicate with the server and only server can validate that.

Comment: ... I don't think I would ever catch Authentication related exceptions in the application; you can't programmatically recover from that because it requires manual intervention (fixing the configuration). There is no problem to solve here - authentication may fail due to bad configuration. Let it blow, make sure stuff is logged.